# How to parse newlines in python RPLY

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

How would I parse newlines using the Rply module in python? I'm making a programming language, and am parsing the following statement:

```
print("hi");
print("hi");
```

But I get the following error:

```py
PS E:\ParserAndLexer> & C:/Python38/python.exe e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/main.py
e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py:87: ParserGeneratorWarning: Token 'ELSE' is unused
  return self.pg.build()
e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py:87: ParserGeneratorWarning: Token '$end' is unused
  return self.pg.build()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/ParserAndLexer/lite/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(parser.parse(tokens).eval())
    self.error_handler(lookahead)
  File "e:\ParserAndLexer\lite\main_parser.py", line 84, in error_handle
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid token {token} {token.value} at {token.getsourcepos()}")
ValueError: Invalid token Token('NEWLINE', '\n')
 at SourcePosition(idx=12, lineno=1, colno=13)
```

I used to be able to bypass this by parsing the statements line by line from a file, but in doing so I was unable to parse multiline if statements, so I switched to parsing the whole file as one string, and cannot bypass the error.

I have something like this:

```py
from rply import LexerGenerator

class Lexer():
  def __init__(self):
    self.lexer = LexerGenerator()
  def _add_tokens(self):
    self.lexer.add("IF", r'if')
    #and so on
    self.lexer.add("NEWLINE", r"\n")
  def lex(self, source):
    self._add_tokens():
    lexer = self.lexer.build()
    return lexer.lex(source)
```

```
from rply import ParserGenerator()
from ast import *

class Parser():
  def __init__(self):
    self.pg = ParserGenerator(...)
  def parse(self):
    @self.pg.production('expression : PRINT LPAREN expression RPAREN SEMICOLON')
    #and so on
  def build_parser(self):
    return self.pg.build()
```

```
from lexer import Lexer
from main_parser import Parser

pg = Parser()
pg.parse()

lexer = Lexer()

parser = pg.build_parser()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    code = f.read()
    lines = f.readlines()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tokens = lexer.lex(code)
    print(parser.parse(tokens).eval())
```

https://github.com/AbooMinister25/ToyLang

Comment: Why do you need to parse newlines? Can't you just ignore them?

Comment: I tried doing `self.lexer.ignore('\n')`, but then I get another invalid token error.

Comment: By the way, you should get in the habit of putting your code in your question, rather than pointing at a code repository which is going to change in the future. See the SO help on creating a [mre].

Comment: "another token error" is probably a different problem.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: Yeah, I added sort of a summary for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newlines here are not a problem. Or rather, the only problem with newlines is that your lexer returns a `NEWLINE`  token to the parser, but the parser doesn't know how to deal with that token. Just ignore newlines in your lexer (by removing the `NEWLINE` token and adding `\n` to the set of ignored characters) and that syntax error will go away.

But that won't let you parse more than one expression, because your grammar only accepts one expression. Specifically, the first non-terminal in your grammar is `expression`, so when you call the `parse` function it expects its input to precisely match some production for `expression`.

In order to parse an input containing several expresssions, you'll need a top-level non-terminal which accepts several expressions. (Make sure that a production for this non-terminal comes at the beginning of your grammar.)

Here's one example. (This might not actually correspond to the language you are trying to define. Also, it there are a number of other issues that it doesn't attempt to correct.)

```
statement_list : 
statement_list : statement_list statement

statement : expression SEMICOLON
statement : IDENTIFIER EQUALS expression SEMICOLON
statement : PRINT LPAREN expression RPAREN SEMICOLON
statement : INPUT LPAREN expression RPAREN SEMICOLON
statement : IF expression COMPARISON expression LBRACKET expression RBRACKET
# Etc.
# The version of IF with newlines was removed. It's unnecessary if
# newlines aren't tokens. But you probably want a version with an ELSE clause.

expression : expression PLUS expression
expression : expression MINUS expression
expression : expression MUL expression
expression : expression DIV expression
expression : INTEGER
expression : STRING
# The following seems to be missing from your grammar
expression : LPAREN expression RPAREN
# Etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question i think you mean to print an empty line
if that is the question you have to type in :

```
enter code here
print("hi");
print("")
print("hi");
```

to make a new empty line between hi

Comment: No, im not trying to print empty lines. The problem im having is that my code is raising an error when I am trying to parse more than one expression.